# PHP implementation of graph algorithms

Tags: php, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I'm not PHP programmer, but I need to make one script and I'd like to have some prepared DFS algorithm in PHP. I think that all programming languages should have at least some library for working with graphs, so I'm not forced to implement it on my own.

Could some experienced PHP programmer tell me, where can I find some free library which will allow me to execute DFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://mirkules.com/blog/?p=20